# Message pending in jms queue even after listener is working fine?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, activemq-classic

I developed two web application as producer and consumer for my project.
Everything works fine except that some message are in pending state (I can see in browser/UI) even after my listener consumes all of them.

Exp:- Producer send 10K, consumer received 10K but I can still see around ~1K messages left in pending state. And if i click purge option in UI then my listener again listen those pending messages.

Reducing pre-fetch policy reduces the pending messages but impact on my consumer's performance.

Producer code :

```
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_BROKER_URL));
        connectionFactory.setUseAsyncSend(new Boolean(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_USE_ASYNC_SEND)));
        connectionFactory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(new Boolean(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_ALWAYS_SESSION_ASYNC)));
        connectionFactory.setOptimizeAcknowledge(new Boolean(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_OPTIMIZE_ACK)));
        connectionFactory.setUserName(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_USERNAME));
        connectionFactory.setPassword(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_PASSWORD));
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(){
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(new Integer(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_SESSION_CACHE_SIZE)));
        cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(new Boolean(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_RECONNECT_ON_EXCEPTION)));
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(new Integer(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_DELIVERY_MODE)));//DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT=1 and DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT=2
        jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(new Integer(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_SESSION_ACK_MODE)));//Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE=1,Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE=2,Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE=3 and Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED=0
        jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeModeName(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_SESSION_ACK_MODE_NAME));
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(new Boolean(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_SESSION_TRANSACTED)));
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_LOG_QUEUE_NAME));
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
```

Consumer code:

```
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConcurrency(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_CONCURRENT_LISTENER));
        factory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_BROKER_URL));
        connectionFactory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(new Boolean(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_ALWAYS_SESSION_ASYNC)));
        connectionFactory.setOptimizeAcknowledge(new Boolean(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_OPTIMIZE_ACK)));
        connectionFactory.setUserName(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_USERNAME));
        connectionFactory.setPassword(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_PASSWORD));
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(){
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(new Integer(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_SESSION_CACHE_SIZE)));
        cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(new Boolean(env.getProperty(JioTUConstant.SYS_JMS_RECONNECT_ON_EXCEPTION)));
        cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }
```

ActiveMQ 5.14.0

Comment: guys, plz rply..... im in real trouble....:P

Comment: if it is unanswered i might have to switch to tibco queue n i can't find anyway to make cachingConnectionFactory for tibco or similar code. So please rply.

Comment: Same issue observed in version ActiveMQ 5.13.0. So now I doubting on myself. I might have missed some basic.